# What is the simplest collatz like problem that is undecidable?

Tags: computational-complexity, collatz-conjecture

I have read that problems resemblings collatz have been shown to be undecidable.
Conway proved that apparantly but Im not sure if the proof was constructive.

So I wonder : What is the simplest collatz like problem that is undecidable ?

Comment: It is problematic to compare the difficulty of undecidable problems.

Comment: Simple refers to the collatz like problem. That is in terms of complexity and length. For instance Collatz has two operations for even or for odd. So Collatz has 2 'if' conditions. 255 'if' conditions is less simple than 10 'if' conditions , assuming they are both linear operators.
Cleary the difficulty of impossible things ( deciding the undecidable ) cannot be compared. I suppose it was a joke.

Comment: Hm, how to be sure that a given statement can't be stated in a "simpler" way?

Comment: @user155124 I would think that a qualitatively "pretty simple" answer would probably suffice, if "simplest" can't be quantified.

Comment: See also [What is the “nearest” problem to the Collatz conjecture that has been successfully resolved?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11611/what-is-the-nearest-problem-to-the-collatz-conjecture-that-has-been-successful).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about *simplest*, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165168/589) by Gerry Myerson cites two papers that prove that some natural generalizations of the Collatz problem are undecidable:

- Conway, "Unpredictable iterations", 1972
- Kurtz and Simon, "The Undecidability of the Generalized Collatz Problem", 2007

There is also a more recent, quite short paper:

- Lehtonen, [Two undecidable variants of Collatz’s problems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2008.08.029), 2008
  *the PDF seems freely available*